# Does an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ only have an inverse if $rank(A)=n$? If so, why?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm currently learning about the rank and inverses of matrices, and every time I attempt to find the inverse of a matrix with a rank smaller than it's number of rows, I find I am unable. One example of this is as follows:

\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\1&0&1\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}

The rank of this matrix is 2 while it has 3 rows, and it doesn't have an inverse. Have I just run into examples where this is true, or is this always true? If it is true, why?

Comment: This is always true. You can check "The fundamental theorem of invertible matrices", for example, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix.

Comment: Rank by definition is  size of largest non-vanishing minor. If determinant of 3 by 3 matrix is zero, then you look at 2by2 minors and compute its determinant. If that comes out to be non zero, then that is your rank.Here in your matrix you have two same rows. So determinat s zero, so rank is less than 3

Comment: @Jake: Don't you mean $n \times n$ in your title ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rank of a matrix is equivalent to the number of nonzero rows after Gaussian elimination. If the rank is not maximal, then there is at least one nonzero row after elimination. Do the determinant about this row, and it will be $0$, i.e., the matrix is not invertible.

Comment: On a technical note, seems straightforward that Gaussian elimination preserves (non-) invertibility, by seeing the effects each transformation used in the elimination has on the determinant.

Comment: But this is using another [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) instead of using the definition of nonsingularity I think?

Comment: @Jack: I am using the equivalence between rank that is not a full rank and the resulting Gaussian elimination, which is, I think, what the OP asked for. What else do you suggest?

Comment: No idea. Hahaha. I guess if there's no direct way to do it, do yours.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the $3 \times 3$ case in general. If $A = [A_1|A_2|A_3]$ then note for $c = [c_1,c_2,c_3]^T$:
$$ Ac = [A_1|A_2|A_3]\left[ \begin{array}{c} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3 \end{array} \right] =c_1A_1+c_2A_2+c_3A_3.$$
Thus, the equation $Ac=0$ is equivalent to the condition $c_1A_1+c_2A_2+c_3A_3=0$. Now, if $\{A_1,A_2,A_3 \}$ is a linearly independent set then we know the condition $c_1A_1+c_2A_2+c_3A_3=0$ implies $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$. On the other hand, the existence of an inverse $A^{-1}$ also allows us to trade $Ac=0$ for $A^{-1}Ac=A^{-1}0$ or $Ic=0$ or more to the point $c=0$. Hence, if the inverse exists, the only solution to $Ac=0$ is just $c=0$. But, as I explained above, this is equivalent to insisting the only solution to $c_1A_1+c_2A_2+c_3A_3=0$ is the zero solution $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$.

Comment: of course, by "general" I mean general invertible $3 \times 3$ case.

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with rank?

Comment: @Jack rank is the number of linearly independent columns. So, to say the matrix has rank 3 is to assume the columns are linearly independent. I suppose I'm missing a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The rank of a matrix is the number of linearly independent column vectors of this matrix, i.e. the dimension of the subspace $\,\operatorname{Im}A$. Furthermore, $A$ can be seen as the matrix associated, in a certain basis,   to a linear map $f\colon K^n\to K^n$ ($K$ is the base field).

For an $n\times n$-matrix, this means that 
\begin{align*}\operatorname{rank}A=n &\iff \operatorname{rank}f=n \iff f\enspace\text{is surjective}\\ &\iff f\enspace\text{is bijective}\iff A\enspace\text{is invertible.}\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

If a matrix $A$ is invertible, then $A\vec x=\vec b$ has a unique solution $\vec x=A^{-1}\vec b$. By the rank theorem we know that $rank(A)+nullity(A)=n$. If $rank(A) < n$, then $nullity(A) \geq 1$. But this means that $A\vec x = \vec 0$ has infinitely many solutions. This is not possible if $A$ is invertible, because we expect a unique solution.